# Find interior width of cars for three car seats

Tags: interior, seat

Does anyone know (other than a tape measure!) of where I can find the interior width from door to door of the rear seats of various car models?

I want to fit three car seats in the back, which removes most small cars.  An older Ford Focus just about fits them in, but the new one is too narrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most car websites will give your measures like rear seat shoulder room or rear seat hip
room. That probably isn't going to be 100% helpful given that car seats tend to have bits and bobs that point out in weird ways (they aren't cubical child pods, after all).

That said, if you lay the seats next to each other with enough separation to adjust belts, you might be able to find some minimal dimensions. If any of the vehicles show hip and shoulder room as less than that number, eliminate them from your search.